# to open outlook mail from java program and to attach file to the mail from directory

Tags: java

I need to implement Email functionality in my Java application which will open microsoft outlook and attach a file from my directory. Has any implemented the same?

Answer (score 10):

According to [these docs](http://www.outlook-tips.net/2011/1298/using-outlook-command-lines) the command you need is

```
"path/to/Outlook.exe /c ipm.note /a \"path/to/attachment\""
```

Assemble this and run it via [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

(Or listen to MarcoS who gives a very good example of why it's sometimes better not to literally answer questions :-))

Answer (score 4):

If you want to implement email functionalities in Java, consider [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html). Also, if your application has email functionalities, then you don't need to open another email client (such as outlook).

Comment: It is ok for a server side application or for some specific use-cases on desktop, but in general, you need SMTP server to send an e-mail. And not many users (statistically, noone) runs it on their local computer. You can use remote SMTP server, but even if you build all support to bypass firewalls and other obstacles, you don't want to do it, as spammers will eat it as an easy lunch.

Comment: @serg.nechaev you need a mail server (SMTP, Exchange, Domino, whatever) in any case to send an email :)

Answer (score 4):

You can open the system's email client using the [desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) class.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI( "mailto:address@somewhere.com" ) )
```

Comment: Yup, but not with an attachment

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to Open MS Outlook 2007 with a HTML email. I have done this using SWT OLE API. Here's the tutorial on Vogela: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html

It says in tutorial that it also works for non-RCP Java.

```
public void sendEMail()
{

    OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(getShell(), SWT.NONE);

    // This should start outlook if it is not running yet
    OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
    site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

    // Now get the outlook application
    OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application");
    OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);

    OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */).getAutomation();

    setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
    setProperty(mail, "Subject", subject);
    setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody", content);

    if (null != attachmentPaths)
    {
        for (String attachmentPath : attachmentPaths)
        {
            File file = new File(attachmentPath);
            if (file.exists())
            {
                OleAutomation attachments = getProperty(mail, "Attachments");
                invoke(attachments, "Add", attachmentPath);
            }
        }
    }

    invoke(mail, "Display" /* or "Send" */);

}
```

Comment: This kind of answer is more useful to the community when you provide an exerpt from the article, in addition to the link. At some point in the future, that link may not be working - and someone finding this answer would then be stuck again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the exact command you want:-

```
new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\OUTLOOK.exe","/a","C:\\Desktop\\stackoverflow.txt").start();
```

First Argument-Path to Outlook.

Second Argument- Outlook attachment command.

Third Argument- Attachment path