# Create email with recipient, subject, body AND attachment

Tags: java, email, outlook, uri, processbuilder

I've been working on an email generating program and I am able to generate an email that has either an attachment upon generation using

```
ProcessBuilder p=new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE","/a","C:\\BackupData.docx");
```

or a generated email with the recipient, subject, and body filled out using

```
URI msg = new URI("mailto", mailer+"&subject="+subject+"?body="+body, (String) null);
```

My issue is that I cannot figure out a way to generate an Outlook email that has both of these features. If there is some way to combine these to create an email with attachment, and populated subject & body, I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: Why aren't you using the API in the `javax.mail` package? See [Sending mail attachment using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117365/sending-mail-attachment-using-java) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE",
    "/c", "ipm.note", // create new e-mail message
    "/m", mailer + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body, // set recipient, subject and body
    "/a", "C:\\BackupData.docx"); // attach file
```

This will start Outlook, open a new e-mail with recipient, subject, and body populated and the file added as attachment.

Beware that in the strings `subject` and `body` the characters `% " & / ? \` have to be encoded using [percent encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

Answer (score 0):

You can open the system's email client using the [desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) class.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI( "mailto:address@somewhere.com" ) )
```

According to [these docs](https://www.outlook-tips.net/how-to/using-outlook-command-lines/) the command you need is

"path/to/Outlook.exe /c ipm.note /a \"path/to/attachment\""

Assemble this and run it via [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Reference from:

[to open outlook mail from java program and to attach file to the mail from directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045816/to-open-outlook-mail-from-java-program-and-to-attach-file-to-the-mail-from-direc)