# java.io.IOException : ipm.note . The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java

Below is the exception thrown when trying to open a create new email for outlook.

**Exception :**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.note": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Exception occurs at first line of below code snippet :

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.note");
            try {
                processBuilder.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I donot specify the switch `/c ipm.note` the code works fine and a new outlook window opens up. But with the switch I get exception. Not sure what's the reason.

I referred following stackoverflow post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045897/2915738 and the related site : https://www.outlook-tips.net/how-to/using-outlook-command-lines/

Please guide me. Let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: If you execute the command in command prompt , are you able to see any error ?

Comment: @Sambit Just tried it. I do not get any error when I run it via cmd. It successfully opens up the new email window.

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace details ? It will give more insight into the problem. Sometime if there is a space like string for accessing files and folder, it gives problem in Windows. Can you try like this . "\""+"C:\\Program Files (x86)"+"\""+File.separator+Microsoft Office+File.separator+"root"+File.separator+"Office16" like this.

Comment: @Sambit Thanks for your help. Minus' solution worked for me. I missed the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split arguments, otherwise it won't work as expected:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE",
  "/c", "ipm.note");
```

Comment: This resolved my issue. I had not split the arguments. Thanks a lot.